# After upgrading so SonarQube 5.4, scans are reporting 0 issues

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I upgraded SonarQube from 5.3 to 5.4 yesterday.

I have Jenkins jobs configured to execute SonarQube Analysis.

I noticed this morning that all of my projects in SonarQube now report 0 issues. (Post SonarQube analysis using 5.4)

I created a new project and ran a scan and this too reports 0 issues.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Diff output from 5.3 (left) and 5.4 (right) logs.

[image: Diff output from 5.3 (left) and 5.4 (right) logs.]

Comment: Do your analysis logs looks the same before and after?

Comment: did you use any database for storing the results or you just used the H2 embedded database provided with the SonarQube?

Comment: I added a picture of the diff logs above.

Comment: I use MySQL database.

Comment: Okay! then I assume that you have configured SonarQube with jenkins in the global configuration. Whether you are using Docker image?

Comment: Which build system do you use? Gradle? maven? or something else?

Comment: I am using Jenkins no Gradle or Maven.  Yes, I have SonarQube configured with Jenkins.  I have been using this same configuration since SonarQube 5.2 and never had a problem after upgrading to 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason why 0 issues were reported after the upgrade was due to the "Quality Profile" having no rules associated with it. For some reason, the upgrade disassociated the rules with the Quality Profile.

Once I added the rules for Java and JavaScript to the Quality Profile and ran a scan, issues are now being reported.